# Maths in programming. Get the angle at point on a parabola

Tags: math, geometry, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity3d + some basic maths I've forgotten by messing around.
Heres what I'm doing now..

[image]

As you can probably tell the sides of this shape form a parabola.
The distance they are out from the centre is the base radius + the height squared * by a constant (0.05 in this image)

The code generating this is very simple..

```
for (int changer = 1; changer > -2; changer-=2) {

        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(
             transform.position.x
            ,transform.position.y + currentheight*changer
            ,transform.position.z - RadiusAtZero -(Mathf.Pow(currentheight,2)*CurveMultiplier)
            );

        var newFleck = Instantiate(Fleck, newPos, Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
        newFleck.transform.RotateAround(transform.position,Vector3.up,angle*changer);

        FleckList.Add(newFleck );

        }
```

Btw the for loop and 'changer' mirror everything so 'currentheight' is really just the distance from the centreline of the parabola.

Anyway I'd like to make the cubes (or flecks as I've called them) be angled so that they are tangentional to the parabola I have made.
I need to determine the angle of a tangent to the parabola at particular point.
I found [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FindingATangentLineToAParabola/)

> to find the line tangent to y=x^2 -3 at (1, -2) we can simultaneously solve
>   y=x^2 -3 and y+2=m(x-1) and set the discriminant equal to zero

But I dont know how to implement this. Also I reckon my 'CurveMultiplier' constant makes my parabola equation different from that one.
Can someone write some code that determines the angle? (and also maybe explain it)

Update. 
Here is fixed version using the derivative of the equation. (Also I have changed from boxes to tetrahedrons and few other superficial things)
[image]

Comment: That link points to a method for finding the tangent line without using calculus. But in this case, why not just use the derivative of the parabola function? The derivative `y' = 2*x` gives you exactly the slope at `x`.

Comment: Aaaahh whats a derivative!!? soz. Can u explain that? whats that apostrophe after y?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if you were familiar with the Calculus or not. A derivative is the infinitesimal rate of change of a function at a given point. That's the same thing as the slope of the function at that point. The "apostrophe" is one type of notation to indicate the derivative of a function of `y = f(x)` (written as `y'` or `f'(x)` or `dy/dx` etc). The value of `y'` at a given `x`, or `f'(x)` is the slope of `f(x)` at that point.

Comment: So in my case.. would the angle be twice the Y value (my parabola is going sideways compared to the examples I'm seeing) Is that angle in radians? Also will that constant I'm scaling the z axis with make a difference, thanks!

Comment: In your picture then I'll assume Y is vertical, X horizontal, and Z in/out of the screen. Then the parabola is `x = 0.05*h^2 + R` (`h` is height, `R` is base radius). If you imagine a plane containing the Y axis, you can rotate the plane around the Y axis at any angle and the dual parabola looks the same. The slope of the tangent of that parabola in that plane is `0.1*h` for a given value of `h`. Since the plane has an angle relative to X and Z axes, then that tangent will also have the same angular component.

Comment: Based on your comment above I made the angle equal to 2 times the "x value" or distance from centreline, and it sorta worked, I made it 3 and now it looks the business  :) http://imageupper.com/i/?S0200010080013E13818047222156273

Comment: OK cool. My original formula (`2y`) was based upon the example equation which came from your link. In my latest comment, I went back and looked at what you said about relation between height, base, etc, and used that (`base radius + 0.05*(height squared)`, leading to a slope of `0.1*h`). You may want to try it. The bottom line is the derivative with respect to `h` for `a*h^n + constant` is `n*a*h` (with `h` being your Y axis). If `3y` is working better than `2y` that may mean the units in the `0.05` factor aren't correct.

Comment: Im going to sleep (very late here) You should post and answer and I will mark it answered. Youve been very helpful, thanks a lot! Now I also know I need to read up about derivatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a derivative for the parabolic equation.

In your picture then I'll assume Y is vertical, X horizontal, and Z in/out of the screen. Then the parabola being rotated, based upon your description, is:

```
f(h) = 0.05*h^2 + R
```

(`h` is height, `R` is base radius). If you imagine a plane containing the Y axis, you can rotate the plane around the Y axis at any angle and the dual parabola looks the same.

The derivative of a parabolic equation of the form `f(x) = C*h^2 + R` is `f'(x) = 2*C*h`, which is the slope of the tangent at `h`. In this specific case, that would be:

```
f'(h) = 0.1*h
```

Since the cross-sectional plane has an angle relative to X and Z axes, then that tangent will also have the same angular component (you have a rotated parabola).

Depending upon the units given for the constants in `f(h)`, particularly the `0.05` value, you may have to adjust this for the correct results.

Comment: OK! I actually was confused by this for aages! I thought your solution would give me the *angle* of the tangent (like in radians) but it actually gives me the *slope* (like a ratio) duh!

Comment: Actually that doesnt work either. The values I'm getting for h*my constant*2 start at 1.2 in the centre of the parabola and increase to 12 as you go out.

Comment: Ok! I seems to work perfectly now. I was using the traditional height (my Z value). When use the Y value it seems prefect. so Y*constant*2

Comment: Thats great @GuyeIncognito. I may not have had my coordinate names correct per your usage, so it sounds like you have it all aligned.

Comment: @GuyeIncognito if you update your graphic link I'd like to see your results :)

Comment: Hey just saw this comment now! Like over one month later! I have posted new pic.